# Should we use the "LIMIT clause" in following example?

Tags: mysql, performance, limit, myisam

```
There is a structure:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Query_1:
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = 1234 
Query_2:
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = 1234 LIMIT 1
```

I need to get just one row. Since we apply `WHERE id=1234` (finding by PRIMARY KEY) obviously that row with id=1234  is only one in whole table.
After MySQL has found the row, whether engine to continue the search when using Query_1?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8713/4 and especially **View Execution Plan**.

You see, that MySQL recognizes the predicate on a PRIMARY column and therefore it does not matter if you add `LIMIT 1` or not.

PS: A little more explanation: Look at the column **rows** of the Execution Plan. The number there is the amount of columns, the query engine thinks, it has to examine. Since the columns content is unique (as it's a primary key), this is 1. Compare it to this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9868b/2 same schema but without primary key. Here **rows** says 8. (The execution plan is explained in the German MySQL reference, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html the English one is for some reason not so detailed.)